# Error 1064 - SQL syntax in MySQL for an INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

i am trying this query but didn't work.

> ERROR: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= (SELECT id_university FROM university WHERE university = "xxx") , `singl' at line 2

```
INSERT INTO `database_charts`.`university_has_single_user` (
        `university_id_university` = (SELECT id_university FROM university WHERE university = "xxx") , 
        `single_user_users_id_user` = (SELECT users_id_user FROM single_user WHERE users_id_user = "1" ), 
        `course_id_course`= (SELECT id_course FROM course WHERE course = "yyy"),
        `year`= "2000" )
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: 1) What do you want to achieve? 2) What do you mean this "didn't work"?

Comment: This isn't a question (http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless MySQL supports a very strange syntax, that's not how you write an INSERT statement. It takes this form:

```
INSERT INTO <TableName> (<Column1,Column2,..,ColumnN>) VALUES (<Value1,Value2,..,ValueN>)
```

So you would have

```
INSERT INTO database_charts.university_has_single_user (
  university_id_university, 
  single_user_users_id_user, 
  course_id_course,year) 
VALUES (
  (SELECT id_university FROM university WHERE university = 'xxx'),
  (SELECT users_id_user FROM single_user WHERE users_id_user = '1' ),
  (SELECT id_course FROM course WHERE course = 'yyy'),
  '2000'
)
```

**Caveat:** I'm not sure whether MySQL will actually handle a nested SELECT for each column value, but the above *is* how INSERT statements are typically written.

Comment: I think, this might throw an error if one of the SELECTs return more than one value. Good answer between, it didn't flash to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 (TABLE2_FIELD)
  SELECT TABLE1_FIELD
  FROM TABLE1 
  WHERE TABLE1_SOMEFIELD IS 'SOMETHING'
```

More here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html

Comment: This is same as @Tadeck's answer, I was typing it while Tadeck posted. Anyway, enjoy.